# opencart multi store 2.x

Tags: opencart2.x, multistore

I have created multi store in my domain with OpenCart 2.0.3.1.

- **Domain**: meramarket.website
- **Sub domain** for multistore: rsmobiles.meramarket.website

when i created the sub-domain i have created the document root to "rsmobiles". then i am getting the permission access error. if i remove the document root, it is re-directing to main root folder. but, it is not showing the logos what i uploaded for "rsmobiles" and when i click on any category, it is re-directing to actual domain (meramarket.website).

Can you guys please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: I got solution for this from outside of this site. the solution is when we are adding url for the 2nd store, we should add http:// in the beginning and / (back slash) at the end

Comment: when we are adding url for the 2nd store, we should add http:// in the beginning and / (back slash) at the end.